# glyph-icons are not displaying in windows 10 internet explorer when font download option is disabled

Tags: asp.net, fonts, bootstrap-4, glyphicons

I have a strange problem in my ASP.NET  application: bootstrap glyphicons not shown in IE  Windows 10 Environment when font download option is disabled.

## My Sample:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: SAN;
  src:url(data:application/font-woff;charset=utf-8;base64,kAIIrKjPVQPTV04FzYTQAQxEG1QAA) format('woff');
}
```

We have been working around to solve the problem to enable font download option.

Do have any other way to solve this?

Comment: If font downloads are disabled, there's no way your icon font will be downloaded. There's really no option other than using a different icon system, e.g. using SVG images.

Comment: RoelN- is it download src:url(data:application/font-woff;charset=utf-8;base64,kAIIrKjPVQPTV04FzYTQAQxEG1QAA) format('woff') ?